# My entire Excel hangs after downloading an Excel from the Internet

Tags: excel, freeze

I am using Office 365 (and have had this problem since moving to Office 365.)

When I load an Excel which has been generated by a web application, then Excel will enter "PROTECTED VIEW"  and will say

> "Be careful - this file may have come from an unsafe source. Unless
>   you need to edit, it's safer to stay in Protected View."

and display a button "Enable Editing"

However, this will sometimes freeze my entire Excel, with either no movement whatsoever or extremely sluggish movement (for instance taking 10 seconds to change one cell of a very small workbook)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to disable Protected View

1. Click File, Options, Trust Center.
2. Click the Trust Center Settings button.
3. Select the Protected View Tab
4. Uncheck as appropriate

Obviously if one disables protection, then one has to be more mindful of where one downloads from, but at least it is possible to work!